# MySQL Catching Exceptions in Transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, exception, transactions

What is the best way to return the cause of an error within a transaction in mysql stored procedure?

Here's one stored procedure I created. But I noticed that if I commit an error on the syntax, say for instance I forget to put the `WHERE` clause in one of the `update` statements, it would only return the `SELECT 'error'` but not the actual cause why the error occurred.

Is there any better way to catch errors just like in Java where you just put

```
catch(SQLException e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getError()+"\n"+e.getMessage() );
}
```

I'd appreciate any example or best practices.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateCurriculumDetails`(p_curriculumId INT, p_editedByUserId INT, p_curriculumName varchar(50), p_description VARCHAR(200), p_gradeLevelId INT, p_schoolYearId INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE hasError BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR sqlexception SET hasError = 1;


    START TRANSACTION;

        UPDATE curriculum_dt c
            SET     c.`name`        = p_curriculumName, 
                    c.description   = p_description,
                    c.gradeLevelId  = p_gradeLevelId 
            WHERE   c.id            = p_curriculumId;

        UPDATE curriculum_schoolyears_dt cs
            SET     cs.schoolYearId = p_schoolYearId
            WHERE   cs.curriculumId = p_curriculumId;

        UPDATE curriculum_hd SET editedBy_UserId = p_editedByUserId,
        dateLastEdited = NOW()
            WHERE curriculumId = p_curriculumId;


    IF hasError THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        SELECT 'error';
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
        SELECT 'successfully updated' AS result;

    END IF;

END
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of a `CONTINUE HANDLER` is entirely inappropriate here.  You're allowing the rest of the queries to run after an error occurs, which is, at best, a waste of time and resources, as you are executing queries you already know will be rolled back.  Instead, something like this seems like a better plan:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK;
  RESIGNAL;
END;
```

The best practice, however, is not to allow the procedure to control the transaction.  If the calling session already holds a transaction, `START TRANSACTION;` inside the procedure will silently and implicitly commit it, leaving the caller in the unenviable position of being unable to rollback and unaware of the condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized after reading your answer that I'm just adding and no other statements come after the update so I realized there's no need to write a continue handler like what you said. Can you explain the part when you say "..is not to allow the procedure to control the transaction"?  Is it not advisable to put Transactions inside stored procedures? Also, I've been reading this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-types.html but when I typed "CALL mysql_errno()" it returned an error on workbench it doesnt exist. Any way to print the error? Tnx.

Comment: `mysql_errno()` isn't a stored procedure.  It's a C function in the C client library (the use of the word "call" in the documentation means to invoke the function, not `CALL` a stored proc).  It is used to fetch the error actually thrown to the client -- not one caught by a handler, so not helpful to you here.  Using `RESIGNAL` as shown above allows you to re-throw the error you just caught, after you clean up.

Comment: It is not a good idea to place control of transactions inside procedures because of the reason mentioned: if you call such a procedure while already in a transaction, your current transaction is silently committed, and when the procedure finishes, you are not in a transaction but you do not realize that fact.  Hopefully you can see how this could lead to unexpected behavior -- spooky action at a distance, as it were.